# C# Process issue

Tags: c#

Well I have 2 Applications and I want to send messages from my first app to my second :

this is the application which handles my second application:

```
enter code here

Console.WriteLine("Set Process and Process Start Info");

        string arr = Console.ReadLine();

        var array = arr.Split('/');

        string processname = array[0];

        string processstartinfo = array[1];

        Process p = new Process();

        p.StartInfo.FileName = processname;

        File.WriteAllText("commandtext.txt", processstartinfo);

        p.Start();
```

and this is my second application

```
enter code here

   var line = File.ReadAllText("commandtext.txt");

        Console.WriteLine(line);





        Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

But the output every time I run the simulation doesnt show me anything . Where am I wrong?

Comment: Did you debug that application at all? Did you step through the code line by line to make sure the variables had the values you expected? Did you check to make sure both applications are reading from and writing to the same file?

Comment: ....and did you look at the contents of the file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I'd suggest [edit]ing the code in your question to remove some of the white space and apply a bit of formatting.  A more description question in the title would also likely be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I did it! You just need to use file streams instead the abstract class File and close the filestream after you use it , use FileMode.Create so every time a new file is created in the place of the old file , and use FileMode.Open to read the data

Comment: If this fully solves the question you asked about, you can accept your own answer.  It's perfectly allowable, though ideally your answer would lay out the information in a way that's easy for other people encountering the same problem to understand.

Comment: Well my description of my solution is quite good. You just need to make the changes to my previous code.